# Perfecting addMatrix Java method

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static int[][] matrixAdd (int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2){
    int[][] sumMatrix = new int[matrix1.length][matrix1[0].length];
    for (int r = 0; r < sumMatrix.length; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix2.length+1; c++){
            sumMatrix[r][c] = matrix1[r][c] + matrix2[r][c];
        }
    }
    return sumMatrix;
}
```

Ok I have this block of code and the code is supposed to add two matrices together and it does that fine. But when two empty arrays are give it gives me an out of bounds error. I have tried using an if-else statement to try and fix it but I still get errors. If anyone can help it would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove the +1 and you should be fine

Comment: you should ideally check to make sure the sizes of the matrices are equal

Comment: There is another logical error in your code: the inner loop runs up to `matrix2.length` (even after removing `+1` as suggested) but should really run up to `sumMatrix[0].length`. If you test only with square matrices, you will not notice this error!

Answer (score 0):

on the first line you are indexin matrix1[0]. If the matrix1 doesn't have any data that will incurr an error.

Check first if matrix1[i] != null before trying to accessing attributes (or calling methods) on it.

This holds for the two matrices you received.

Also, as mentioned, the +1 will guide you to another out-of-bouds since length is already greater than the last index of an array or matrix.